# VS Code выделяет русский язык, как убрать?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code выделяет абсолютно все русские символы, это достаточно раздражает, думала проблема в настройке Editor › Unicode Highlight: Ambiguous Characters, но не помогло
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Навести мышь на подсвеченный текст, прочитать что пишет vscode, посмотреть предлагаемые действия. Если там пишет про Unicode Highlight: Ambiguous Characters, но эта настройка не помогла, то скорее всего нужно перезапустить редактор.

Comment: Навелась вылезла другая настройка, но в итоге VS Code предложил выключить подсветку, спасибо

Comment: А как настройка в итоге называется?